# Remove HR tag from last row in table

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove the HR tag from the last row in a table.

Here's my jQuery

```
$("#tableOptionResults tr:last td").find('hr').remove();
```

and here's the same HTML:

```
 <tr class="shadedRow">
   <td colspan="3">
     <hr />
   </td>
 </tr>
```

What am I missing?

**Edit**

This is definitely my fault. The HR wasn't in the last row. I ended up using `$('#tableOptionResults tr hr:last').remove();` to make it work.

Comment: Seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/Fhx8a/

Comment: You're right Xyan, the problem was that the hr wasn't in the last <TR> so I wound up doing this instead $('#tableOptionResults tr hr:last').remove();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#tableOptionResults tr:last-child hr').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you could simplify this by adding the `hr` to the initial selector, this works fine for me. A number of things to be sure of:

- You have the correct ID for your table, i.e. `<table id="tableOptionResults">`
- The `<hr />` you are trying to remove is definitely the last `<tr>` in the above table
- Your HTML validates

Comment: Well I have egg on my face. You're right. It wasn't in the last <TR>. I ended up doing this: $('#tableOptionResults tr hr:last').remove(); and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".shadedRow").find('hr').remove()
```

Comment: Presumably, there might be other rows with class `.shadedRow` that aren't the *last* row of the table. Answer is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

try as a pseudo element [css_pseudo_elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

`$("#tableOptionResults tr:last-child td").find('hr').remove();​`